# Is 'puzzling' like questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm finding questions about puzzles and found this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801138/how-to-add-some-code-to-get-2-2-3-in-console

I know this question is rarely constructive and hardly be useful for future visitors, but in fact this is a programming question, with clear problem set and expected behaviour (at least I think),and it is answerable even it almost surely lacks practical usage, is it on topic?

Comment: The dupe is not really clear about it so my though is It would be on topic on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ (and there's already some questions of this kind there). And if you're after puzzle, you'll find interesting ones there.